# x86 32-bit Assembly - Position of Print Effects Behavior

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction

I'm currently working on a compiler for a subset of Java and can translate the code to x86 32-bit assembly. I've been able to compile a few programs, but the following program has been giving me trouble:

```
class DummySort {
    public static void main(String[] a){
        DS ds = new DS();
        ds.Start(12);
    }
}


// This class contains the array of integers and
// methods to initialize, print and sort the array
class DS{

    int[] number ;
    int size ;

    // Invoke the Initialization, Sort and Printing
    // Methods
    public void Start(int sz){
        int aux01 ;
        aux01 = this.Init(sz);
        System.out.printf("%s\n","----- UNSORTED -----");
        this.Print("U");
    }

    // Print array of integers
    public void Print(String s){
        int j = 0;
        int n = 0;
        while (j < (size)) {
            //Switching prints change behavior
            System.out.printf("%d at %d with %s\n",number[j],j,s);
            n = j;
            j = j + 1 ;
            //System.out.printf("%d at %d with %s\n",number[n],n,s);
        }
    }

    // Initialize array of integers
    public int Init(int sz){
        size = sz ;
        number = new int[sz] ;

        number[0] = 20 ;
        number[1] = 7  ; 
        number[2] = 12 ;
        number[3] = 18 ;
        number[4] = 2  ; 
        number[5] = 11 ;
        number[6] = 6  ; 
        number[7] = 9  ; 
        number[8] = 19 ; 
        number[9] = 5  ;
        number[10] = 25;
        number[11] = 0;
        return 0 ;  
    }

}
```

The main problem comes from switching between which print statement to use. The first results in an infinite loop which prints:

```
7 at 1 with U
```

Using the second print instead of the first results in the following and terminates:

```
----- UNSORTED -----
2 at 4 with U
2 at 4 with U
2 at 4 with U
2 at 4 with U
2 at 4 with U
2 at 4 with U
2 at 4 with U
2 at 4 with U
2 at 4 with U
2 at 4 with U
2 at 4 with U
2 at 4 with U
```

This is the assembly my program generates in the above case:

```
    .file   "DummySort.s"
    .section     .rodata
STR0:
    .ascii "%d at %d with %s\12\0"
STR1:
    .ascii "%s\12\0"
STR2:
    .ascii "----- UNSORTED -----\0"
STR3:
    .ascii "U\0"
    .text
    #CODEBLOCK: prog: 0
    #CODEBLOCK: DS
    #CODEBLOCK: DS:new
DS_new:
    pushl  %ebp
    movl  %esp, %ebp
    #CODEBLOCK: save
    pushl  %edx
    pushl  %ebx
    pushl  %ecx
    pushl  %esi
    #END_BLOCK: save

    pushl  $8
    call  _malloc
    addl  $4, %esp
    #CODEBLOCK: restore
    popl  %esi
    popl  %ecx
    popl  %ebx
    popl  %edx
    #END_BLOCK: restore

    movl  %eax, %esi
    #CODEBLOCK: varDec: 14
    movl  $0, (%esi)
    #END_BLOCK: varDec: 14

    #CODEBLOCK: varDec: 18
    movl  $0, 4(%esi)
    #END_BLOCK: varDec: 18

    movl  %esi, %eax
    movl  %ebp, %esp
    popl  %ebp
    ret
    #END_BLOCK: DS:new

    #CODEBLOCK: DS:Methods: 0
    #CODEBLOCK: DS:Start
DS_Start:
    pushl  %ebp
    movl  %esp, %ebp
    #CODEBLOCK: varDec: 20
    movl  $0, -4(%ebp)
    #END_BLOCK: varDec: 20

    #CODEBLOCK: assignStat: 21
    #CODEBLOCK: save
    pushl  %edx
    pushl  %ebx
    pushl  %ecx
    pushl  %esi
    #END_BLOCK: save

    #CODEBLOCK: call
    pushl  8(%ebp)
    call  DS_Init
    addl  $4, %esp
    #END_BLOCK: call

    #CODEBLOCK: restore
    popl  %esi
    popl  %ecx
    popl  %ebx
    popl  %edx
    #END_BLOCK: restore

    movl  %eax, %edx
    movl  %edx, -4(%ebp)
    #END_BLOCK: assignStat: 21

    #CODEBLOCK: funcStat: 22
    #CODEBLOCK: save
    pushl  %edx
    pushl  %ebx
    pushl  %ecx
    pushl  %esi
    #END_BLOCK: save

    #CODEBLOCK: call
    pushl  $STR2
    pushl  $STR1
    call  _printf
    addl  $8, %esp
    #END_BLOCK: call

    #CODEBLOCK: restore
    popl  %esi
    popl  %ecx
    popl  %ebx
    popl  %edx
    #END_BLOCK: restore

    #END_BLOCK: funcStat: 22

    #CODEBLOCK: funcStat: 23
    #CODEBLOCK: save
    pushl  %edx
    pushl  %ebx
    pushl  %ecx
    pushl  %esi
    #END_BLOCK: save

    #CODEBLOCK: call
    pushl  $STR3
    call  DS_Print
    addl  $4, %esp
    #END_BLOCK: call

    #CODEBLOCK: restore
    popl  %esi
    popl  %ecx
    popl  %ebx
    popl  %edx
    #END_BLOCK: restore

    #END_BLOCK: funcStat: 23

    movl  %ebp, %esp
    popl  %ebp
    ret
    #END_BLOCK: DS:Start

    #CODEBLOCK: DS:Print
DS_Print:
    pushl  %ebp
    movl  %esp, %ebp
    #CODEBLOCK: varDec: 28
    movl  $0, -4(%ebp)
    #END_BLOCK: varDec: 28

    #CODEBLOCK: varDec: 29
    movl  $0, -8(%ebp)
    #END_BLOCK: varDec: 29

    #CODEBLOCK: whileStat: 36
WHILE1:
    movl  -4(%ebp), %edx
    xor   %eax, %eax
    cmp   4(%esi), %edx
    setl  %al
    movl  %eax, %edx
    cmp  $0, %edx
    je    ENDWHILE1
    #CODEBLOCK: blockStat: 36
    #CODEBLOCK: funcStat: 32
    #CODEBLOCK: save
    pushl  %edx
    pushl  %ebx
    pushl  %ecx
    pushl  %esi
    #END_BLOCK: save

    #CODEBLOCK: call
    pushl  8(%ebp)
    pushl  -4(%ebp)
    movl  -4(%ebp), %edx
    movl  (%esi), %ebx
    pushl  (%ebx,%edx,4)
    pushl  $STR0
    call  _printf
    addl  $16, %esp
    #END_BLOCK: call

    #CODEBLOCK: restore
    popl  %esi
    popl  %ecx
    popl  %ebx
    popl  %edx
    #END_BLOCK: restore

    #END_BLOCK: funcStat: 32

    #CODEBLOCK: assignStat: 33
    movl  -4(%ebp), %eax
    movl  %eax, -8(%ebp)
    #END_BLOCK: assignStat: 33

    #CODEBLOCK: assignStat: 35
    movl  -4(%ebp), %edx
    addl  $1, %edx
    movl  %edx, -4(%ebp)
    #END_BLOCK: assignStat: 35

    #END_BLOCK: blockStat: 36

    jmp   WHILE1
ENDWHILE1:
    #END_BLOCK: whileStat: 36

    movl  %ebp, %esp
    popl  %ebp
    ret
    #END_BLOCK: DS:Print

    #CODEBLOCK: DS:Init
DS_Init:
    pushl  %ebp
    movl  %esp, %ebp
    #CODEBLOCK: assignStat: 41
    movl  8(%ebp), %eax
    movl  %eax, 4(%esi)
    #END_BLOCK: assignStat: 41

    #CODEBLOCK: assignStat: 43
    movl  8(%ebp), %edx
    imul  $4, %edx
    #CODEBLOCK: save
    pushl  %edx
    pushl  %ebx
    pushl  %ecx
    pushl  %esi
    #END_BLOCK: save

    pushl  %edx
    call  _malloc
    addl  $4, %esp
    #CODEBLOCK: restore
    popl  %esi
    popl  %ecx
    popl  %ebx
    popl  %edx
    #END_BLOCK: restore

    movl  %eax, %edx
    movl  %edx, (%esi)
    #END_BLOCK: assignStat: 43

    #CODEBLOCK: arrAssignStat: 44
    movl  $20, %edx
    movl  $0, %ebx
    movl  (%esi), %ecx
    movl  %edx, (%ecx,%ebx,4)
    #END_BLOCK: arrAssignStat: 44

    #CODEBLOCK: arrAssignStat: 45
    movl  $7, %edx
    movl  $1, %ebx
    movl  (%esi), %ecx
    movl  %edx, (%ecx,%ebx,4)
    #END_BLOCK: arrAssignStat: 45

    #CODEBLOCK: arrAssignStat: 46
    movl  $12, %edx
    movl  $2, %ebx
    movl  (%esi), %ecx
    movl  %edx, (%ecx,%ebx,4)
    #END_BLOCK: arrAssignStat: 46

    #CODEBLOCK: arrAssignStat: 47
    movl  $18, %edx
    movl  $3, %ebx
    movl  (%esi), %ecx
    movl  %edx, (%ecx,%ebx,4)
    #END_BLOCK: arrAssignStat: 47

    #CODEBLOCK: arrAssignStat: 48
    movl  $2, %edx
    movl  $4, %ebx
    movl  (%esi), %ecx
    movl  %edx, (%ecx,%ebx,4)
    #END_BLOCK: arrAssignStat: 48

    #CODEBLOCK: arrAssignStat: 49
    movl  $11, %edx
    movl  $5, %ebx
    movl  (%esi), %ecx
    movl  %edx, (%ecx,%ebx,4)
    #END_BLOCK: arrAssignStat: 49

    #CODEBLOCK: arrAssignStat: 50
    movl  $6, %edx
    movl  $6, %ebx
    movl  (%esi), %ecx
    movl  %edx, (%ecx,%ebx,4)
    #END_BLOCK: arrAssignStat: 50

    #CODEBLOCK: arrAssignStat: 51
    movl  $9, %edx
    movl  $7, %ebx
    movl  (%esi), %ecx
    movl  %edx, (%ecx,%ebx,4)
    #END_BLOCK: arrAssignStat: 51

    #CODEBLOCK: arrAssignStat: 52
    movl  $19, %edx
    movl  $8, %ebx
    movl  (%esi), %ecx
    movl  %edx, (%ecx,%ebx,4)
    #END_BLOCK: arrAssignStat: 52

    #CODEBLOCK: arrAssignStat: 53
    movl  $5, %edx
    movl  $9, %ebx
    movl  (%esi), %ecx
    movl  %edx, (%ecx,%ebx,4)
    #END_BLOCK: arrAssignStat: 53

    #CODEBLOCK: arrAssignStat: 54
    movl  $25, %edx
    movl  $10, %ebx
    movl  (%esi), %ecx
    movl  %edx, (%ecx,%ebx,4)
    #END_BLOCK: arrAssignStat: 54

    #CODEBLOCK: arrAssignStat: 55
    movl  $0, %edx
    movl  $11, %ebx
    movl  (%esi), %ecx
    movl  %edx, (%ecx,%ebx,4)
    #END_BLOCK: arrAssignStat: 55

    #CODEBLOCK: returnStat: 56
    movl  $0, %eax
    movl  %ebp, %esp
    popl  %ebp
    ret
    #END_BLOCK: returnStat: 56

    #END_BLOCK: DS:Init

    #END_BLOCK: DS:Methods: 0

    #END_BLOCK: DS

    #CODEBLOCK: _main
.globl _main
_main:
    #CODEBLOCK: mainPre
    pushl  %ebp
    movl  %esp, %ebp
    #END_BLOCK: mainPre

    #CODEBLOCK: mMtdLocs
    subl  $4, %esp
    #END_BLOCK: mMtdLocs

    #CODEBLOCK: varDec: 4
    #CODEBLOCK: save
    pushl  %edx
    pushl  %ebx
    pushl  %ecx
    pushl  %esi
    #END_BLOCK: save

    call  DS_new
    #CODEBLOCK: restore
    popl  %esi
    popl  %ecx
    popl  %ebx
    popl  %edx
    #END_BLOCK: restore

    movl  %eax, %edx
    movl  %edx, -4(%ebp)
    #END_BLOCK: varDec: 4

    #CODEBLOCK: funcStat: 5
    #CODEBLOCK: save
    pushl  %edx
    pushl  %ebx
    pushl  %ecx
    pushl  %esi
    #END_BLOCK: save

    #CODEBLOCK: call
    pushl  $12
    movl  -4(%ebp), %esi
    call  DS_Start
    addl  $4, %esp
    #END_BLOCK: call

    #CODEBLOCK: restore
    popl  %esi
    popl  %ecx
    popl  %ebx
    popl  %edx
    #END_BLOCK: restore

    #END_BLOCK: funcStat: 5

    #CODEBLOCK: mainEnd
    movl  $0, %eax
    movl  %ebp, %esp
    popl  %ebp
    ret
    #END_BLOCK: mainEnd

    #END_BLOCK: _main

    #END_BLOCK: prog: 0
```

I've been looking at this code for hours and any help is greatly appreciated. I can post the assembly generated in the second case, but it appears to be entirely the same besides the positioning of the codeblocks.

If anyone has any requests for more generated examples, please let me know and thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Start` and `Print` you don't allocate space for the locals from the stack. Ie. you are missing the `sub $x, %esp`. Thus, your pushes and calls will overwrite the locals, wreaking havoc.

```
$ ./a.out
----- UNSORTED -----
20 at 0 with U
7 at 1 with U
12 at 2 with U
18 at 3 with U
2 at 4 with U
11 at 5 with U
6 at 6 with U
9 at 7 with U
19 at 8 with U
5 at 9 with U
25 at 10 with U
0 at 11 with U
```

Yay! \o/